# Operating on dynamic memory, is it meaningful to overload a const memeber function?

Tags: c++, class, constants, smart-pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

An exercise from *C++ Primer 5 Edition* made me stuck, which goes like

> Exercise 12.3: Does this class need const versions of **push_back** and
>   **pop_back**? If so, add them. If not, why aren’t they needed? (Page 458)

Below is the class. Definitions for members `front` and `back` are omitted to simplify the codes.

```
class StrBlob 
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::size_type size_type;
    StrBlob();
    StrBlob(std::initializer_list<std::string> il);
    size_type size() const { return data->size(); }
    bool empty() const { return data->empty(); }
    // add and remove elements
    void push_back(const std::string &t) {data->push_back(t);}
    void pop_back();
    // element access
    std::string& front();
    std::string& back();
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> data;
    // throws msg if data[i] isn't valid
    void check(size_type i, const std::string &msg) const;
};

StrBlob::StrBlob(): data(make_shared<vector<string>>()) { }
StrBlob::StrBlob(initializer_list<string> il):
          data(make_shared<vector<string>>(il)) { }

void StrBlob::check(size_type i, const string &msg) const
{
    if (i >= data->size())
        throw out_of_range(msg);
}

void StrBlob::pop_back()
{
    check(0, "pop_back on empty StrBlob");
    data->pop_back();
}
```

I tried to overload a const member `void StrBlob::pop_back() const` as below.

```
void StrBlob::pop_back() const
{
    check(0, "pop_back on empty wy_StrBlob");
    data->pop_back();
}
```

Compiler complained nothing about this const member. wondering am I doing right? Is there any possibility that this const member can be called? Is it meaningful to add this const member? Why?

Comment: You can test your hypothesis by *not* adding the `const` member functions, then declaring a `const StrBlob` object, and finally trying to call `push_back()` and/or `pop_back()` on it. If you get a compiler error, then you do need the `const` version of the member functions in question.

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain in this case, as `data` is a pointer (semantically), so pointer semantics apply: a `some_type* const` is different from a `some_type const*`. The "type" of `this->data` in a `const` member function is `shared_ptr<vector<string>>> const`, not `shared_ptr<vector<string> const>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can certainly do this if you want to, but there doesn't seem to be any logical reason. The compiler doesn't complain because this doesn't modify `data` (which is a pointer) but rather the thing `data` points to, which is perfectly legal to do with a `const` pointer.

Comment: Wouldn't `const` overloads break the convention of `const` member functions not modifying the observable state (`size()`, `empty()`) of the object?

Comment: @DyP Absolutely. That's why there doesn't seem to be any logical reason to do it.

Comment: Ah, you've hidden it there ;) I thought you were referring to `void pop_back()` and `void pop_back() const` having the same "functionality" (as opposed to `iter begin()` vs. `const_iter begin() const`).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can I sum up this way: `void pop_back()` and `void pop_back() const`  provide different functionality, but adding the latter one has little logical meaning?

Comment: @Alan.W Exactly. It's just a way to make `const` behave illogically for the class.